# Meteor show objects only if logged in, reactive

Tags: meteor

I am very new to Meteor, I have a simple problem that can't find a right answer too.

I want to show a component only if they are logged In.

I tried to do it this way

```
     Template.newPost.rendered= function(){
     if(Meteor.user()){
         $('#submit-btn').show();
         $('#submit-text').hide();
     }
     else{
         $('#submit-btn').hide();
         $('#submit-text').show();
              }
}
```

but problem is it get rendered before the Meteor.user() get loaded. 
I think I am doing this the hard way is there any reactive way to do this simpler? if not, how can I make this approach work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using blaze, you can skip all that and just use the [currentuser helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentuser) in your template like this:

```html
{{#if currentUser}}
  <button id="submit-btn">Click me</button>
{{else}}
  <p id="submit-text">Please log in to submit</p>
{{/if}}
```